# Node js Error in Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, loopbackjs

I have developed a project using Loopback. I am trying to deploy it to Openshift. I am using openshift-cartridge-strongloop. when i am creating an application to openshift. 
During installation it shows

```
remote: npm ERR! peerinvalid The package chai does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
remote: npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer chai-json-schema@1.0.10 wants chai@>= 1.6.1 < 2
remote: npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer chai-fs@0.0.3 wants chai@>= 1.6.1 < 2
```

After deploying it is running successfully at

> http://even3co-codisl.rhcloud.com/explorer/

But in the rhc tail i am getting the error bellow. What is wrong with it?

```
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
    npm ERR! command "/var/lib/openshift/55bf03dc7628e1eadc000089/strongloop//bin/node/node" "/var/lib/openshift/55bf03dc7628e1eadc000089/strongloop/bin/node/npm" "start" "-d"
    npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/55bf03dc7628e1eadc000089/app-root/runtime/repo
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/55bf03dc7628e1eadc000089/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: check `/var/lib/openshift/55bf03dc7628e1eadc000089/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log` for errors.

Comment: Are you by any chance using angular? Because googling ELIFECYCLE error code got me a lot of responses for an angular bug.

Comment: @slebetman I am just building a API that does not have any coupling on to any front end.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal How can i check the debug log on openshift. Is there any helpfull link?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I have checked the errors. It says

11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls Event-Management
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
13 error command "/var/lib/openshift/55bdc1d089f5cfb0400001b3/strongloop//bin/node/node" "/var/lib/openshift/55bdc1d089f5cfb0400001b3/strongloop/bin/node/npm" "start" "-d"
14 error cwd /var/lib/openshift/55bdc1d089f5cfb0400001b3/app-root/runtime/repo
15 error node -v v0.10.30
16 error npm -v 1.4.21
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]